# How return two or more elements in front of .push($(this).val());?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I have a function that submits information to create a prerequisite on my database. Information "templates" and "version" are on the same checkbox (look the picture for understand) and with my code, i want to get the *id_template* and the *version* but I just have the *id_template*. What can replace `push($(this).val())` to get these two elements?

[template_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOO19.png)

```
var templates = [];

console.log(templates);
console.log($(this));
if(mode == 'create') {
    if( $('.selectTemplateRow:checked').length > 0 ){
        $('.selectTemplateRow:checked').each(function(){
            templates.push($(this).val());
        });
    }
}


var project_name = $('#project_name').val();
var sharepointLink = $('#sharepointLink').val();


var data = { _token: CSRF_TOKEN, project_name : project_name, id_user : id_user[0], id_template :id_template, id_template : id_template, version :version, sharepointLink : sharepointLink};
```

Comment: Hi, you can use `$(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text()`  inside the `each` loop to get version value of the selected row .